# Trig Substitution Problem - Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I want to integrate this (I chose an easy one):
$$\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$
Method 1: (Trig Substitution) $x=2\sec(\theta)$
$$\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\int \frac{\sec(\theta)\tan{(\theta)}}{|\tan(\theta)|}d\theta$$

Now removing the absolute value I find is tough. The inverse secant function splits out values of $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$, and $\pi/2$ to $\pi$. How can I resolve this? Tangent is positive from $0$ and $\pi/2$ - first quadrant, and negative from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$. I know most books overlook this, but I want to be most accurate.

I say "Method 1" because I also have another question right after this.

Comment: Why the absolute value? That is not common place in these types of problems. I suggest dropping the absolute value and cancelling the tangents. This leaves you with just an integral of secant. For that , I highly recommend looking up the answer. That thing is just about impossible to integrate without a ridiculously clever trick.

Comment: Are you trying to find the antiderivative for $x > 2$ or for $x < -2$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, not sure what you mean, but I do want to split the integral from when $\tan(\theta)>0$ and $\tan(\theta)<0$ user166967, we have an absolute value, one does not simply ignore it. Doing that, you are losing half of the solution. I have $|\tan(\theta))|$, which CAN be POSITIVE and NEGATIVE depending on the domain.

Comment: That being said, I do know the antiderivative of secant, which you can get by multiplying top and bottom by secantx+tangentx.

Comment: That is the trick. I still don't understand your absolute value claim. Shouldn't that mean the absolute value of the tangent in the numerator needs to be taken as well? If you are doing this simply because tangent takes on positive and negative values, I should point out that all trig functions take on positive and negative values.

Comment: I think you can rewrite this integral by using pythagorean theorem. It eventually became the integral of sec(x). I never encountered a need for absolute value bars.

Comment: I've asked this question on another forum, and indeed, the absolute value bars are necessary. That is because $\sqrt{\tan^2x}=|\tan x|$. And it just so happens that tangent can be both positive and negative, so we have to consider both cases, right?

Comment: That being said, the absolute values are ignored in most textbooks, but they aren't able to back up that claim. They are restricting the range of the inverse secant more than it already is...they are only taking in consideration when $\theta$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, and ignoring what happens when $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, which is when tangent takes a negative value. @user166967, I'm not just randomly adding absolute values. It occurs in the integrand; check: $\sqrt{x^2-4}=\sqrt{4(\sec^2 \theta-1)}=2\sqrt{\tan \theta}=2|\tan \theta|$

Comment: You may want to look into the derivative of $\cosh^{-1}x$

Comment: @TylerHG
I know the derivative of arcosh. That's not my question. I purposely picked a simple integral, this applies for ALL substitutions involving $x=a \sec \theta$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the integrand $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ is only defined on $(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$.

Hence, we can consider the antiderivative on $x > 2$ and on $x < -2$ seperately.

If $x > 2$, then we substitute $x = 2\sec \theta$ where $0 < \theta < \tfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Over this range, $\tan \theta > 0$. So, $\sqrt{x^2-4} = 2\tan \theta$, and thus,

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \int \dfrac{2\sec \theta \tan \theta}{|2\tan \theta|} \,d\theta = \int \dfrac{\sec \theta \tan \theta}{\tan \theta} \,d\theta = \int \sec \theta \,d\theta$

$= \ln|\sec\theta + \tan \theta|+C = \ln\left|\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right|+C = \ln\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right)+C$

If $x < -2$, then we substitute $x = 2\sec \theta$ where $\tfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$.

Over this range, $\tan \theta < 0$. So, $\sqrt{x^2-4} = -2\tan \theta$, and thus,

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \int \dfrac{2\sec \theta \tan \theta}{|2\tan \theta|} \,d\theta = \int \dfrac{\sec \theta \tan \theta}{-\tan \theta} \,d\theta = -\int \sec \theta \,d\theta$

$= -\ln|\sec\theta + \tan \theta|+C = -\ln\left|\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right|+C = \ln\left|\dfrac{1}{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}}\right|+C$.

$= \ln\left|\dfrac{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}}{\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right)}\right|+C = \ln\left|\dfrac{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2-4}{4}}\right|+C = \ln\left|\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right|+C$

As you can see, the two expressions are the same. So, in this case, we don't lose anything by carelessly writing $\sqrt{x^2-4} = 2\tan \theta$ instead of $|2\tan \theta|$.

Alternatively, if $x < -2$, then substitute $x = 2\sec \theta$ where $\pi < \theta < \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Then $\tan \theta > 0$ over this range, and so, we don't need to worry about the absolute value signs.

Comment: Jeez, that was perfect, and the answer I was looking for :D

Comment: But just a quite question...how does x>2 imply that $0<\theta <\pi/2$?

Comment: We need to pick a range for $\theta$ such that for every $x > 2$ we can write $x = 2\sec \theta$ for exactly one value of $\theta$ in our range. One such range is $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, although there are several other choices.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how you figured out that the range must be $0 < \theta < \pi/2$. How did you work that out?

Comment: Try looking at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+2*sec%28x%29) of $x = 2\sec \theta$. You'll see that as $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$, $x$ increases from $2$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here:
$$= -\ln|\sec\theta + \tan \theta|+C = -\ln\left|\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right|+C = \ln\left|\dfrac{1}{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}}\right|+C$$

Did you construct a right angled triangle? If our substitution was $x=2\sec (\theta)$, then we would have a triangle with hypotenuse $x$, and adjacent 2, or am I missing something?

Comment: I did not construct a right angled triangle. If $x = 2\sec \theta$ then $\sec \theta = \frac{x}{2}$. Also $\sqrt{x^2-4} = \sqrt{4\sec^2\theta - 4} = 2\sqrt{\sec^2 \theta - 1} = 2\sqrt{\tan^2 \theta} = 2|\tan \theta|$. For the range $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$, we have $\tan \theta < 0$, so $\sqrt{x^2-4} = -2\tan \theta$. Thus, $\tan\theta = -\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}$.

Comment: Take makes sense...how would we do it the right triangle method? We start with $x = 2\sec \theta$...I was thinking to just draw a normal right angled triangle, with hypotenuse $x$ and opposite $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ and just make the $\tan$ negative because we're in the 2nd quadrant, but that doesn't make complete sense. For example: consider $\int \frac {x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$. The domain is $-\pi/2, \pi/2$ if we use a $\sin$ substitution. It's in BOTH the 1st and 4th quadrant, so having two different triangles will give two different answers, yet we know the integral only has ONE answer.

Comment: I think I figured something out, let me know if it sounds right:

Our substitution was $x = 2 \sec(\theta)$

Then our triangle is hypotenuse $x$, adjacent $2$, the opposite is $+/- \sqrt{x^2-4}$.

The plus / minus is important. We will have $\sqrt{x^2-4}=\sqrt{4 \tan^2(\theta)}=2|\tan(\theta)|$

When $\tan(\theta)>0$, we use the $+\sqrt{x^2-4}$, and when $\tan(\theta)<0$, we use the $-\sqrt{x^2-4}$ as the opposite side.